# get function error in c. trying to return string value.

Tags: c

I am trying to use the getinput function to return string values as entered by the user. but i have gotten errors of 1. conflicting types for 'getinput' 2. previous implicit declaration of 'getinput' was here. Could someone explain to me what are those errors?

the gets function is supposed to read in two different sentences from the user and store it in the variable userinput1 and userinput2.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char input1[1000] = {0};
    char input2[1000] = {0}; 

    int main(){
      getinput();
      char input[2000]; 
      sprintf(input, "%s %s", input1, input2); 
      printf("%s\n", input);
      return 0;
    }

    const char * getinput() { 
     printf("please enter the something\n"); 
     scanf("%999[^\n]%*c", input1); 
     printf("please enter the next input\n"); 
     scanf("%999[^\n]%*c", input2); 
     return input1, input2; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
return input1, input2;
```

uses the comma operator and returns `input2`.
Since you have declared `input1` and `input2` as file scope variables, there is no need to return them--they are in scope in both `main()` and `getinput()`. Delete the return line and use

```
void getinput(void);

int main (void)
{  ... }

void getinput (void)
{
   ...
}
```

I'd also recommend a look at

```
scanf("%999[^\n]%*c", input2);
```

Did you perhaps mean just

```
scanf(" %999[^\n]", input2);
```

Note the extra blank which skips all white space (e.g. a previous newline).

Answer (score 1):

Add function declaration of `getinput()` at top of your code as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * getinput();

...
```

If compiler has not seen a function declaration it assumes that it returns `int`, but your function actually returns `char *`, hence such error/warning.

Also, you cannot return multiple values in `C`. Considering your code, you don't need to return `input1` and `input2` as they are global variables.

In case you want to return multiple values either you return array (if they are of similar type) or return them through a structure.

Comment: Definitely not the only problem check the return statement

Comment: It's worth noting, as mentioned in Jens answer, that `return input1, input2;` is actually valid C — the comma operator evaluates each expression, and returns the value of the last operand. It just a) doesn't do what the OP expects, and b) is completely unnecessary, as pointed out.

Comment: @MattPatenaude, yes, that is what I tried to explain in answer that returning multiple values does not work as expected by OP.

Comment: @PEARR Why did you accept this answer? It completely misses to address your problems. After that your program has still the same bugs and won't do what you want.

Comment: @PEARR; Read answer by @Jens again.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char input1[1000] = {0};
char input2[1000] = {0}; 
const char * getinput();

int main(){
getinput();
char input[2000]; 
sprintf(input, "%s %s", input1, input2); 
printf("%s\n", input);
return 0;
}

const char * getinput() { 
printf("please enter the something\n"); 
scanf("%999[^\n]%*c", input1); 
printf("please enter the next input\n"); 
scanf("%999[^\n]%*c", input2); 
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Not returning anything from a non-void function. And `const char * getinput();` is not a prototype, it's a deprecated old-style (K&R) function declaration.